# Unity 3D | Aiming Down Sight's

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have my script that I created, but when I right click everything goes well, it plays the aim animation and stop when it ends, but when you release it, it re play's the animation. Can anyone help?

```
#pragma strict

function Update () {

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

   animation.Play("Shotgun_Shoot");

}

if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)){

   animation.Play("Shotgun_Aim");

}
else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)){
   animation.Rewind("Shotgun_Aim");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because of

```
else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)){
  animation.Rewind("Shotgun_Aim");
}
```

This happens when the user releases the button

It says in the Unity API for this function

> Returns true during the frame the user releases the given mouse button.
>   You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user has pressed the mouse button and released it again. button values are 0 for left button, 1 for right button, 2 for the middle button.

So you don't want that last else if

EDIT:

How about telling the animation also to stop if the mouse buttons are released?

> Animation.Stop -- Stops all playing animations that were started with this Animation.
>   Stopping an animation also Rewinds it to the Start.

Comment: It still repeats the animation over and over?

Comment: @TheEvil_potato I edited my answer again: how about telling the animation to stop when the buttons are released?